# ng-repeat issue and html table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am not sure how to get the range of my headerRow so that when I am ng-repeating the rows it knows how many there are to get the correct offset.

```
   <table class="table">
     <tr>
       <th ng-repeat="header in headerRow">{{ header }}</th>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="row in fewRows">
       <td>{{ row[need this to be the range of the length of the headerRow] }}</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: `headerRow.length` will give you total number and `$index` will give you the current index iterated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're just using arrays for `headerRow` and `row`, and row can have more elements but not fewer than `headerRow`, but all indexes in the `row` and `headerRow` arrays correspond to the same fields?  Seems like a weird way to operate, but you could repeat over your `headerRow` again just to get the index and use that with your `row` array...

```
 <tr ng-repeat="row in fewRows">
   <td ng-repeat="h in headerRow">{{ row[$index] }}</td>
 </tr>
```

I really can't see though where you would design it like that, a more elegant or meaningful way would be for rows to be objects and to have meaningful headers with the column name, etc.  Then re-arranging the `headerRow` array would let you move/hide columns instead of just representing a different column count...

```
 <tr ng-repeat="row in fewRows">
   <td ng-repeat="h in headerRow">{{ row[h.columnName] }}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I appropriate it! I know it might seem like a strange way to design it the way I have and most likely I'll have to refractor it quite a lot of it sometime soon but I just wanted something that'll work for right now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

in ngRepeat context you have access to a $index var that represent the index of loop.
Try use it on your code.

```
{{ row[$index] }}
```